# Обратная связь для PUSH-уведомлений

Tags: symfony2, rest, уведомления

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста
Есть задача: процесс должен доставать из БД некие сущности (назовем их "Клиентами" - смартфоны) и по очереди слать им PUSH-уведомления. Клиент как-то реагирует на PUSH (жмет "да" или "нет" или ничего не делает за определенный промежуток времение). Как можно отловить обратную связь от клиента применительно к идеологии REST? Только HTTP-запросом? И как реализовать таймаут ответа?
Может есть готовые решения для Симфони?

Comment: К, слову, речь об этих уведомлениях https://w3c.github.io/push-api/?

Comment: клиенты это что нативные приложения или веб страницы? [Эти уведомления](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API) ещё только в разработке и практически ничем не поддерживается